# How to print a SVG using firefox

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to print the organisation tree on my webpage which is under a svg.

I set the size as per below.
Any hint on how to print the svg chart displayed in Firefox?

```
</style>


<svg width="1800" height="4500"></svg>


<script src="file://d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(250,0)");
```

Comment: Press Ctrl-P on the keyboard

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far, what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and the relevant code in an [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I tried to use the window.print() function but it is not printing the entire chart.

Comment: Ctrl-P is the same. I would like to print the svg width="1800" height="4500"> when pressing a button. Thank you for your responses